# How to pass the one output from one process to another process in Nextflow?

Tags: bioinformatics, dsl, nextflow

So I am new to nextflow, I am trying to pass the bam file produced by `ALIGNMENT` process to the `MKDUP` process but its throwing a null value error.
I kind of understood the error, its due to the `${sample_id}` in the `MKDUP` process. But I don't know how to do it.

```
params.rawFiles = "/mnt/NGS1/WES_Analysis/test/*_{1,2}.fq.gz"
params.genome = "/mnt/NGS1/WES_Analysis/Database/resources_broad_hg38_v0_Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta"
params.outDir = "/mnt/NGS1/WES_Analysis/test/Output"

// println "reads: $params.rawFiles"

log.info """\
         genome: ${params.genome}
         rawFiles: ${params.rawFiles}
         Output Dir: ${params.outDir}
         """
         .stripIndent()



process FASTP {
    debug true

    publishDir "${params.outDir}/${sample_id}/Quality", mode:"copy"
    
    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(reads)

    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("${sample_id}_trim_*.fq.gz"), emit: reads
    path("${sample_id}.fastp.json"), emit: json
    path("${sample_id}.fastp.html"), emit: html

    script:
    """
    echo ${reads[0]}
    fastp --in1 ${reads[0]} --in2 ${reads[1]} \
    -q 20 -u 20 -l 40 --detect_adapter_for_pe \
    --out1 ${sample_id}_trim_1.fq.gz --out2 ${sample_id}_trim_2.fq.gz \
    -w 16 --json ${sample_id}.fastp.json --html ${sample_id}.fastp.html
    """
}


process ALIGNMENT {
    debug true

    publishDir "${params.outDir}/${sample_id}/BAM_Files", mode:"copy"

    input: 
    tuple val(sample_id), path(reads)

    output:
    path("${sample_id}_alignSort.bam"), emit: alignSortBam
    path("${sample_id}_alignSort.bam.bai")



    script:
    """
    echo ${reads[0]}
    bwa mem -M -t 70 \
    ${params.genome} ${reads[0]} ${reads[1]} \
    -R "@RG\\tID:${sample_id}\\tSM:${sample_id}\\tPL:MGI\\tPU:Lane1\\tLB:MGI" | samtools view -S -b | \
    samtools sort -o ${sample_id}_alignSort.bam
    samtools index -@ 7 ${sample_id}_alignSort.bam ${sample_id}_alignSort.bam.bai
    echo The path of sample_alignSort.bam is: ${sample_id}_alignSort.bam
    """
}

process MKDUP {
    debug true

    publishDir "${params.outDir}/${sample_id}/BAM_Files", mode:"copy"

    input: 
    tuple val(sample_id), path(alignSortBam)

    output:
    path("${sample_id}_alignSortMkDup.bam")

    script:
    """
    echo mkdup :- ${alignSortBam}
    gatk MarkDuplicatesSpark -OBI true \
    -I ${alignSortBam} \
    -O ${sample_id}_alignSortMkDup.bam \
    -M ${sample_id}_metrics.txt
    """
}

workflow{
    read_pairs_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.rawFiles )

    FASTP( read_pairs_ch )
    ALIGNMENT(FASTP.out.reads)
    MKDUP(ALIGNMENT.out.alignSortBam)
}
```

Comment: can you please try `ALIGNMENT(FASTP.reads)
    MKDUP(ALIGNMENT.alignSortBam)` (without the out). Also , show us the exact error message.

Comment: @Pierre If I run without the `out` parameter, it throws the following error :-

`No such variable: alignSortBam

 -- Check script 'wes.nf' at line: 94 or see '.nextflow.log' file for more details
`

And this is the line 94:- `MKDUP(ALIGNMENT.alignSortBam)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally what you want is to be able to match up the input and output declarations. You could use the [map](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#map) operator to transform the items in the channel. But the usual way is to just have the ALIGNMENT output declaration also produce a [tuple](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#output-type-tuple), which would match the MKDUP input declaration. It's also best to keep your BAM and index file together, rather than use a separate output channel. For example:

```
params.rawFiles = "/mnt/NGS1/WES_Analysis/test/*_{1,2}.fq.gz"
params.genome = "/mnt/NGS1/WES_Analysis/Database/resources_broad_hg38_v0_Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta"
params.outDir = "/mnt/NGS1/WES_Analysis/test/Output"
```

```
process FASTP {

    tag { sample_id }

    publishDir "${params.outDir}/${sample_id}/Quality", mode:"copy"
    cpus 16

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(reads)

    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("${sample_id}_trim_{1,2}.fq.gz"), emit: reads
    path("${sample_id}.fastp.json"), emit: json
    path("${sample_id}.fastp.html"), emit: html

    script:
    def (r1, r2) = reads

    """
    fastp \\
        --in1 "${r1}" \\
        --in2 "${r2}" \\
        -q 20 \\
        -u 20 \\
        -l 40 \\
        --detect_adapter_for_pe \\
        --out1 "${sample_id}_trim_1.fq.gz" \\
        --out2 "${sample_id}_trim_2.fq.gz" \\
        -w ${task.cpus} \\
        --json "${sample_id}.fastp.json" \\
        --html "${sample_id}.fastp.html"
    """
}
```

```
process ALIGNMENT {

    tag { sample_id }

    publishDir "${params.outDir}/${sample_id}/BAM_Files", mode:"copy"
    cpus 32

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(reads)
    path bwa_index, stageAs: 'bwa_index/*'

    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("${sample_id}_alignSort.bam{,.bai}")

    script:
    def idxbase = bwa_index[0].baseName
    def (r1, r2) = reads

    """
    bwa mem \\
        -t ${task.cpus} \\
        -R "@RG\\tID:${sample_id}\\tSM:${sample_id}\\tPL:MGI\\tPU:Lane1\\tLB:MGI" \\
        -M \\
        "bwa_index/${idxbase}" \\
        "${r1}" \\
        "${r2}" |
    samtools view -S -b |
    samtools sort -o "${sample_id}_alignSort.bam"
    samtools index "${sample_id}_alignSort.bam"
    """
}
```

```
process MKDUP {

    tag { sample_id }

    publishDir "${params.outDir}/${sample_id}/BAM_Files", mode:"copy"

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(indexed_bam)

    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("${sample_id}_alignSortMkDup.bam"), emit: bam
    path "${sample_id}_metrics.txt", emit: metrics

    script:
    """
    gatk MarkDuplicatesSpark -OBI true \\
        -I "${indexed_bam.first()}" \\
        -O "${sample_id}_alignSortMkDup.bam" \\
        -M "${sample_id}_metrics.txt"
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    read_pairs_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.rawFiles )
    bwa_index = Channel
        .fromPath( "${params.genome}.{amb,ann,bwt,pac,sa}" )
        .collect()

    FASTP( read_pairs_ch )
    ALIGNMENT( FASTP.out.reads, bwa_index )
    MKDUP( ALIGNMENT.out )
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me, thanks a lot. Actually I am used to Snakemake and this is different than snakemake so got confused. And also I had to change the ref_fasta parameter in ALIGNMENT process as it was not taking the whole path due to which the bam file wasn't getting generated. So I changed it back to ${params.genome} and then it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry @NikhilPanchal I made a silly mistake in my answer, which I will fix soon. BWA MEM requires the index files, not the FASTA file per se. If you use `${params.genome}`, these will not be localized into the process working directory when the job is run.

Comment: No worries, you already helped me much. So what we can use instead of `${params.genome}`?

Comment: @NikhilPanchal The solution is to still use a channel to stage in the files, but instead of passing in the FASTA file (which isn't actually needed to run BWA MEM), we pass in the required index files. Please see my changes above, thanks!

Comment: So `stageAs` is similar to `emit` but for input files?

Comment: Your edited code worked like a charm, Thank you so much.
I just have to understand that `input` and `def idxbase = bwa_index[0].baseName`

Comment: No worries at all @NikhilPanchal! The [`stageAs`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#multiple-input-files) option just allows you to control how the file or files should be named in the process working directory. It's not strictly necessary here, but it should help keep things organized. So BWA MEM requires the basename of the index files so that it can find/load the genome indices. BWA packs the sequences (into the .pac file), so you don't even need the FASTA file to run BWA MEM after it's been indexed. We can just take the first file in the collection to get the basename.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251454/discussion-between-nikhil-panchal-and-steve).